# How can I make RSpec output to console when run as a command %x[rspec] from Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class with an instance method that runs RSpec using the `%x[]` notation:

```
class TestRunner
  def run_rspec
    # do stuff
    %x[rspec spec -c -f documentation]
    # do more stuff
  end
end
```

When I do this:

```
> tr = TestRunner.new
> tr.run_rspec
```

The documentation (group and example names) does not appear in the console.

To contrast, when I run `rspec` straight from the command line I get this:

```
$ rspec spec -c -f documentation

  a group name
    an example
    another example
    ...
```

I **don't** want to do this:

```
puts %x[rspec spec -c -f documentation
```

Because then the output all spits out in one huge clump at the very end. I want it to run in "real time," with each example showing up as each test is run.

Is there a way, with the setup I have, to get RSpec to announce what it's doing, as it's doing it (as it does when run normally from the command line)?

Comment: Did you try the [open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been advised that `system()` and the other shell methods can be dangerous to use, so I've opted to switch to the even-better approach of using RSpec itself:

```
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(['spec', '-c', '-f', 'documentation'])
```

rather than calling it via shell from my Ruby script.

---

Ruby offers several options for running programs from the command line. I was using `%x[]`, the wrong choice for my use case.

**Solution:** Use `system()`, not `%x[]` -- `rspec` will write to `STDOUT` in real-time when I call it with `system('rspec spec')`.

---

Some background in case it's helpful to anyone who stumbles upon this question:

Consider the differences between Ruby's command-line options:

- `%x[command]` accumulates the result of `command` and returns it, in one chunk.
- `exec('command')` will output `command` as `command` runs, but will replace whatever process called it -- i.e., if you use `exec` in your Ruby script, your Ruby script won't finish.
- `system('command')` executes `command` in a subshell, and returns to the calling script.

This is why `system` was the choice for my script.